# ClassNotFoundException for class BrowserView at runtime

Tags: maven, classnotfoundexception, jxbrowser

In Java project using Maven I add library for JxBrowser.

Program is compiling fine - with no errors, but when I try to run it in Intelij IDEA it returns error.

It shows when try to create BrowserView object(it is a class in lib package com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing) and returned two errors `NoClassDefFoundError` and `CLassNotFoundException` and full message looks like :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/BrowserView
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.jxbrowser.JxBrowser.<init>(JxBrowser.java:26)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.market.view.window.StockBoxWindowController.lambda$createMenuWindow$17(StockBoxWindowController.java:211)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.menuDragMouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:943)
    at javax.swing.JMenuItem.fireMenuDragMouseReleased(JMenuItem.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JMenuItem.processMenuDragMouseEvent(JMenuItem.java:483)
    at javax.swing.JMenuItem.processMouseEvent(JMenuItem.java:429)
    at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.processMouseEvent(MenuSelectionManager.java:329)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:879)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
```

How can I resolve it ?

When I type `BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView()` it is not highlighted, it means that lib was found in project resources.

pom.xml contains:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxbrowser-mac</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</id>
        <url>http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When compiling project, the library is downloaded successfully with no error.

**EDIT**

I work on OS X system and IntelliJ IDEA.
I add license.jar file in module settings - Dependencies tab, ask me about which type and I choose "classes" also it is setted to "Compile"

**EDIT 2**

I checked `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and there is no .jar files to JxBrowser... But why ? When it is set up in module dependencies

Comment: The problem is likely in how the jar is packaged, but you're not showing how that is done at all. Please provide more details about the pom and what jars you end up with after packaging, and where they are relative to each other.

Comment: But the problem is when I run project in Intelij IDAE, not running from jar. Creating package is OK - do not return error.

Comment: Show me where in your question you mention IntelliJ? Then you'll have to start to detail how you setup your project as there must be something wrong there.

Comment: I create module with Maven. In Maven add dependencines to maven repository with JxBrowser and newest version 6.11.1, compile Project and maven download this JxBrowser libs - I can create object of it with warning but when I run app I get error as in quesiton.

Comment: Please make sure that you include your license.jar file into your application class path.

Comment: I checked the compiled .jar file and unpack it but JxBrowser lib is not there. @Vladimir can You explain ? I am using Intelij IDAE and Maven. Where I should checked it ?

Comment: To use JxBrowser you need to include the license.jar file into your application class path: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012859-licensing Maven repository doesn't include license.jar, so you need to obtain the license and include it into your application class path manually.

Comment: Ok I add now the license.jar to classpath (using intelij IDEA, in module settings> dependencies tab) but error is the same.

Comment: We created IntelliJ IDEA project with JxBrowser configured via Maven. Everything works fine. No exceptions or errors. It looks like the issue is in your IDEA project configuration. To tell what causes this issue I need to look at your IDEA project and reproduce the issue locally. Using only exceptions stack trace it's hard to suggest something.

Comment: I solved it. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

In JxBrowser installation guide ([JxBrowser Installation](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012860-installation)) there was no information about adding dependency as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxbrowser</artifactId>
    <version>${jxbrowser.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

only for different systems (as Windows, Mac, Linux), but not to main lib.